# Get an input value from a td from a parent in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get the input value of the *input.salePrice*. Here is the HTML :

```
<tr role="row" id="0">
    <td class="v-align-middle semi-bold">TEST</td>
    <td class="v-align-middle text-right quantityModule">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon primary"><a href="#" class="quantityMinus"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control text-center quantity" data-v-min="0" data-v-max="999" data-w-empty="zero" value="1" autocomplete="off" style="width:50px;">
            <span class="input-group-addon primary"><a href="#" class="quantityPlus"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></a></span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="v-align-middle text-right priceModule">
        <div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control text-right salePrice" value="24.00" autocomplete="off" style="width:80px;"><span class="input-group-addon primary">%</span></div></td><td class="v-align-middle text-right">24.00
    </td>
</tr>
```

I started something wrong like this :

```
$('#orderTable tbody').on('click', 'a.quantityPlus', function() {
    var salePrice = $(this).parents('tr input.salePrice').val();
});
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it was really simple, here is the code :

```
$('#orderTable tbody').on('click', 'a.quantityPlus', function() {
    var tr = $(this).parents('tr').find('input.salePrice').val();
});
```